# Trying to relate two lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two Model level functions that populate two arrays, `my_favorite_brands` and `my_favorites`. They are defined as follows:

```
def self.my_favorite_brands
  brand_list = Array.new
  Favorite.my_favorites.each do |favorite|
    brand_list.push(favorite.style.shoe.brand)
  end
  brand_list.uniq
end
```

And here is `my_favorites`:

```
def self.my_favorites
  Favorite.where(:user => current_user)
end
```

I want to print out each `Brand` in `my_favorite_brands` and while doing so, for each `Brand` print out all of it's associated `Favorites` in `my_favorites`. The relation between the two models `Brand` and `Favorite` is the following. `Brand` has many `Shoes` which has many `Styles`. `Favorite` belongs to `Style` and it belongs to `User`. Here is some probably non-functional pseudo-ish (in that it doesn't really work) code that emulates what I want to do.

```
#Controller stuff
@fav_brands = Brand.my_favorite_brands
@fav_favorites = Favorite.my_favorites
#in the view
favorites_by_brand = Array.new
@fav_brands.each do |brand|
  favorites_by_brand = @fav_favorites.map do |favorite|
    unless favorite.style.shoe.brand == brand
      @fav_favorites.delete("favorite")
  end 
  favorites_by_brand.each do |favorite|
    puts favorite.style
  end
end
```

I am trying to create a complete list of favorites where `favorite.style.shoe.brand` is equal to the current brand I am iterating over, so that I can display the styles by `Brand`.

Comment: As an aside, you can define `self.my_favorite_brands` as just `Favorite.my_favorites.map { |f| f.style.shoe.brand }.uniq`.

Comment: How is `Brand.my_favorite` defined?

Comment: @mbratch sorry that's a typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to accomplish what I want to accomplish, although it's probably not Ideal .

```
styles_of_favorites = @fav_favorites.map {|favorite| favorite.style}
@fav_brands.each do |brand|
  brand.shoes.each do |shoe|
    shoe.style.each do | style|
      if styles_of_favorites.include?(style)
        puts style
       end
     end
   end
end
```